# Add Attachment base64 image in MailMessage and read it in html body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email-attachments

Currently I have to send emails with `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` but I need to send a picture that is currently in `base64` `string` within the `MailAddress` body.

I have understood that it is necessary to put it in the `Attachment`, but I don't know how to put `base64` in `MailMessage` class and then read it in order to visualize image in the body of the email. I don't have url image path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send inline image in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**To embed image into your mail message:** (Its **not** same as adding an attachment file to message)

You dont need to convert image to base64 if you are using system.net.mail namespace to send your mail.

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
var imageToInline = new LinkedResource("Your image full path", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            imageToInline.ContentId = "MyImage";
            alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(imageToInline);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(body);
```

**Update:**

This is somewhat hacky way of embedding image to your mailMessage.

```
Byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage("Your base64 image string"));
System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);

public static string FixBase64ForImage(string Image)
{
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image, Image.Length);
        sbText.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty); sbText.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        return sbText.ToString();
}


var mail = new MailMessage();
var imageToInline = new LinkedResource(streamBitmap , MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
imageToInline.ContentId = "MyImage";
alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(imageToInline);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(body);
```

And your html mail body should have following tag:

```
 <img alt ="" src ="cid:MyImage"/>
```

Comment: But I need to send the image with the email, yes?  and the only data that I have it is the base64 image.

Comment: You want to show image in email or add it as attachment like any other zip file?

Comment: I want to show image into email. But my image it's base64.  string image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh....."; How can I put it in email body or convert it?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you just want to convert base64 image to bitmap then refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5083417/6170142)

Comment: I 'm checking .

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me. Just worth mentioning that if you have a byte array to insert to the email start from 
`System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);` line

Answer (score 22):

Completed method to convert a body HTML to an AlternateView

**bodyHtml** example (you can pass it into the **MailMessage** code block below)

```
<p>example</p>
<p><img src=\ "data:image/jpeg;base64,---base64string---"></p>
<p>example</p>
<p><img src=\ "data:image/png;base64,---base64string---"></p>
<p>something</p>
```

With this method, you can visualize multiple images by many ESPs (gmail, outlook,...)

```
private static AlternateView ContentToAlternateView(string content)
    {
        var imgCount = 0;
        List<LinkedResource> resourceCollection = new List<LinkedResource>();
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(content, "<img(?<value>.*?)>"))
        {
            imgCount++;
            var imgContent = m.Groups["value"].Value;
            string type = Regex.Match(imgContent, ":(?<type>.*?);base64,").Groups["type"].Value;
            string base64 = Regex.Match(imgContent, "base64,(?<base64>.*?)\"").Groups["base64"].Value;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(type) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(base64))
            {
                //ignore replacement when match normal <img> tag
                continue;
            }
            var replacement = " src=\"cid:" + imgCount + "\"";
            content = content.Replace(imgContent, replacement);
            var tempResource = new LinkedResource(Base64ToImageStream(base64), new ContentType(type))
            {
                ContentId = imgCount.ToString()
            };
            resourceCollection.Add(tempResource);
        }

        AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        foreach (var item in resourceCollection)
        {
            alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(item);
        }

        return alternateView;
    }
```

Convert Base64 to Stream:

```
public static Stream Base64ToImageStream(string base64String)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        return ms;
    }
```

Set up MailMessage :

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;                   
AlternateView alterView = ContentToAlternateView(bodyHtml);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(alterView);
//more settings
//...
//////////////
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Host, Port) { EnableSsl = false };
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Great answer.

Comment: works well. but the class attribute and inline styles applied on the img tag will be removed, any idea ?

Comment: @BilalHalayqa , fixed this code to support custom attributes, such as styles https://gist.github.com/dima-horror/4594d510d94e4b56256427c15ca005e9

Comment: Perfect answer. Still works.

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
     <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, <!-- base64 data --> />
   </body>
```

use img tag as above in HTML of mail

or you can attach as below

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(base64String);
attachment.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
mailmessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I Attach base64 image into MailMessage class?

Comment: why do you want to attach if you can visualize the image using HTML body of email?

Comment: I think that encoded inline images is not supported by many email clients

Comment: I am using same approach, but its not working. My `base64String` length is 19000+, and because of this, its throwing an error at `Attachment attachment = new Attachment(base64String);`.

Comment: @AksheyBhat `PathTooLongException`: too long file name

Comment: @Antosha at what line you are getting the exception? I am not using any paths in my code

Comment: @AksheyBhat solved by using stream Attachment at = new Attachment(stream, new ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")). Don't forget to reset stream before passing: stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: This code makes no sense, there's no overload of Attachment constructor that takes a base64 string, it expects a path or a stream.  `new Attachment(base64String);`

Comment: This is not going to work as many client stopped support for this