# Add a Base64 image to a mail in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a picture to the mail I am sending in C#, and I found some code in here - stackoverflow. (the question: [Add Attachment base64 image in MailMessage and read it in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407474/add-attachment-base64-image-in-mailmessage-and-read-it-in-html-body)).
but this code is giving me syntax errors in C# I don't know how to solve correctly... here is my code:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
public static string FixBase64ForImage(string Image)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image, Image.Length);
            sbText.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty); sbText.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            return sbText.ToString();
        }
        public static bool SendEmail2(string mailToGet, string subject, string message, string image)
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(image));
                System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                var imageToInline = new LinkedResource(streamBitmap, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                imageToInline.ContentId = "MyImage";
                alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(imageToInline);//here there is an error
                mail.AlternateViews.Add(body);//here there is an error
                //from now on - my code:
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message+= "<img alt ='' src ='cid: MyImage'/>";
                mail.Body = message;
                mail.Subject = subject;                
                mail.To.Add(mailToGet);
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmailAdress", "myPassword");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

I have two errors: one on line `alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(imageToInline);`, where it says: **The name 'alternateView' does not exist in the current context**, and one on line `mail.AlternateViews.Add(body);`, where it gives the same - on the **body**.
I tried creating these elements here, but it only got me into more trouble... I don't even know if I am using the right **using**s (by the way, I put these by the demand of C#, not as part of the code I copied). Can anyone tell me what this code means and where I was wrong? and if you know, what should I do to repair this?

Comment: why you don't use the second answer from that topic, it's very detailed

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your alternateView does not exist because you did not instanciate it, to do this you need to add this line before:

```
AlternateView alternateView = new AlternateView("MyImage");
```

Where **"MyImage"** is the name of the file. And in regards to the **body** error you need to add that alternating view that you just created, so instead of "body" you just need to put **alternateView** like so:

```
mail.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);
```

Comment: `new AlternativeView("MyImage")` doesn't work, because the image is not a file saved somewhere - it's a string representing it, it came like that from SQL and so is not saved anywhere. Do you have an advice for this situation?