# How to convert web stream getting from httpwebresponse to Bitmap and how to show converted image as response

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am getting stream from httpwebresponse which is send by the another web server, here i want to convert this web stream to Bitmap and then this converted image is used to show as response in c#.

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse())
                    { 
                        if (myResp.ContentType.Contains("image/jpeg"))
                        {
                            Stream myStream = myResp.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: what is the format of your data in the stream ?

Comment: Maybe [Stream to byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream) => [byte\[\] to Base64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)  => [Base64 to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083336/decoding-base64-image)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myResp.GetResponseStream());
```

You can convert stream to image like that

Comment: i already used this... is there another way to convert to image?

Comment: leave it bro, then how to convert stream to bitmap?