# Convert from base64 string to long in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, base64, md5

Hi I have some strings generated using the following code:

```
private static string CalcHashCode(byte[] data)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    Byte[] hash = md5Provider.ComputeHash(data);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

How can I get a unique **long** from a encoded base64 string, I mean, the opposite operation, and then convert it to long?

```
private long CalcLongFromHashCode(string base64Hashcode)
{
  //TODO
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base64 decode in C# or Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915898/base64-decode-in-c-sharp-or-java)

Comment: Is that *really* the opposite operation?

Comment: Converting an MD5 to a long won't work without significantly truncating your hash value.  MD5 spits out a 128-bit number, and a long is 64 bits (for now).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't convert a base-64 string to a `long` (or it might be truncated if it doesn't fit, as `long` uses only 8 bytes)...

It's possible to convert it to a byte array (which is '*the opposite*' operation):

```
 byte[] hash = new byte[] { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69 };
 string string64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
 byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(string64);
```

If your array contains at least 8 bytes, then you could get your long value:

```
long longValue = BitConverter.ToInt64(array, 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

First, convert the string to a byte[],

```
var array = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Hashcode);
```

then convert the byte array to a long

```
var longValue = BitConverter.ToInt64(array, 0);
```

As has been mentioned, you'll get truncation.

---

The opposite direction:

```
var bits = BitConverter.GetBytes(@long);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bits);
```

Examples:

```
218433070285205504 : "ADCMWbgHCAM="
long.MaxValue : "/////////38="
```