# Convert base64 encoded integer to long

Tags: .net

I am returning some `XML` like below in `SQL Server 2016`. If I do the `CONVERT` option I get this error below.  I don't want that error and would like to return the current type for this odd text `AAAAAAF+nuc=`.  Am I able to convert this in `.NET` to a `long`?

> Explicit conversion from data type timestamp to date is not allowed.

**XML**

```
<Assets>
  <Asset>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <FileName>179605.png</FileName>
    <Id>179605</Id>
    <Version>AAAAAAF+nuc=</Version>
    <Version1>25075431</Version1>
  </Asset>
</Assets>
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
    ga.[Type], ga.[FileName], ga.Id, ga.[Version], 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, ga.[Version]) AS [Version1]
FROM 
    Test ga
WHERE 
    ga.id = 179605
FOR XML PATH('Asset'), ROOT('Assets')
```

**Example Try**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Convert()
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String("AAAAAAF+nuc=");
            var longValue = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0); // -1756828261867847680
        }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]. Note that most people here want properly formatted text, not images. (Copy-and-paste...)

Comment: I guess you're right. So add the <sql-server> tag. (<sql> is for general ANSI/ISO SQL.)

Comment: `timestamp` in SQL Server *isn't* a date and time value, it's a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value, and has literally nothing to do with dates or times.

Comment: Your value is Base64 of the `rowversion` value, and will be exactly 8 bytes when converted. As mentioned, it has nothing to do with dates. What other format would you like it to be instead? One option could be `convert(varchar(10), cast(Version as binary(8)), 1)` which would give you `0x` and the hexadecimal bytes, another option is `cast(Version as bigint)`

Comment: I am not sure if you are all following.  The error says that but I am not doing anything with date.  The problem is the `explicit conversion` warning, not what type of conversion.  I want to take `AAAAAAF+nuc=` and in .NET convert it to a long.

Comment: I need this done at the .NET level, is anyone getting this?

Comment: @MikeFlynn no one is getting this because you're saying you want to do it in .net, but you're not showing the code producing this error... You want to convert some value to long in .Net, what have you done about this so far ? And where are you stuck ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197491/convert-from-base64-string-to-long-in-c-sharp

Comment: I tried that @PaulKaram but it gives me a really long negative number.  I posted it in the question.

Comment: it's because of LittleEndian byte order reversed. try `Array.Reverse(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);` just before "toInt64"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well what do you know, got this exact answer from SQL Server using this code.  If there is a faster way please comment.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Convert()
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String("AAAAAAF+nuc=");
            Array.Reverse(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            var longValue =  BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0); // 25075431
        }
```

Comment: you are welcome. next time just simply ask how to base64 decode to int64 in c#... option(hi, please, thank you,smile)

Comment: If I knew it was base64 then I would of.

Comment: What should be part of the question? I love how you downvote the exact answer for NO reason.