# How do I decode an encoded Base64 zip file to a new zip file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, base64, zip

I'm trying to create a zip file out of an encoded base64 string, but I'm stuck at getting the files from the string.

I have been able to create the zip file out of it, but I don't see the file that should be in it.

My code so far:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .Build();

    var fileName = args[0];
    var path = $"{config["zipPath"]}\\{fileName}";

    byte[] zipBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(args[1]);
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(zipBytes))
    {
        // without this I can't open my zip file
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
        }

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
   }
}
```

**Clarification**

The string that I'm decoding is an encoded zip file. I get the Base64 string and I need to decode it and create a zip file that is the same as the original, including the files that were zipped.

**Further Clarification**

I receive a zip file from a third party. However, I do not receive it as a zip file, I receive it as an encoded Base64 string. The bytes of that zip are encoded to a Base64 string. 
What I need to do is to recreate that original zip file, using the Base64 string that I received.

Comment: what is in `args[1]`? the Base64 string? and what is in `args[0]`???

Comment: @FalcoAlexander args[0] = the name of the zip file, args[1] = the Base64 string of the encoded zip file

Comment: I cannot quite follow...you need to create a temp file with the base64 string in it and this file should be in a new .zip file? then you are obviously missing sth.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I just need the zip file and I want it to be the same as the original zip file that was encoded to Base64, so including the files in the original zip file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 decode in C# or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915898/base64-decode-in-c-sharp-or-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the ZipFile method [CreateFromDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .Build();

    var fileName = args[0];
    var path = $"{config["zipPath"]}\\{fileName}";
    string extractPath = @"c:\users\exampleuser\extract";

    byte[] zipBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(args[1]);
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(zipBytes))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(extractPath);
        }

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(extractPath, path);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter at all, what kind of file you are getting, because you receive a binary representation and a filename of it. It can be a `.JPG`,  a `.VHD` virtual disk, a `.MDB` database, whatever.

So you can omit the memoryStream and theZipArchive, you simply write the binary data to a file with .zip extension:

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"c:\temp\fileName2.zip";
    byte[] zipBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(zipBytes,0,zipBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

(I created a base64 String from a .zip before)

```
var path = @"c:\temp\import.zip";
    string base64 = "";

    using (FileStream zip = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var zipBytes = new byte[zip.Length];
        zip.Read(zipBytes,0,(int)zip.Length);
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(zipBytes);
    }
```

Comment: this seems to create a new entry, what I want is to have the original entries of my original zip file

Comment: obviously your question is very unclear, see also the other answer? No idea what you try to achieve...

Comment: yes, strange, but I think I got it. are you sure the Bas64 string you got is correct? your code looks fine for this, even I don't understand the use of `ZipArchive` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Read all text from the file:

example:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\demofile.txt");
```

Then turn the base64 string, from the text file, into bytes

example:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

Then you can write those bytes to a zip file

example:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\demofile_zip.zip", bytes);
```

If you want to extract in memory just load it into a memorystream

example:

```
using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(bytes2))
{
    using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(@"C:\demofile_installer.msi"))
    {
        using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The base64 already is a zip. I need to create a zip out of it. I do not get the files it contains seperately